# How can I get MkDocs with Arithmatex and MathJax to recognize \\[ ... \\] as display math delimiters?

Tags: mathjax, mkdocs

I'm using [MkDocs 1.2.2](https://www.mkdocs.org) with [MathJax 3.2](https://www.mathjax.org) via [Arithmatex](https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/arithmatex/) from the [pymdown-extensions](https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/).  I'm trying to get Arithmatex to recognize math inside `\\[` and `\\]` (instead of the default `\[` … `\]`) as display math. Starting with a basic config,

```
markdown_extensions:
  - footnotes
  - pymdownx.arithmatex
  - pymdownx.highlight
  - pymdownx.superfences
extra_javascript:
  - javascripts/mathjax-config.js
  - https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6
  - https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-svg-full.js
```

where `mathjax-config.js` contains exactly [the code under the tab "Default – MathJax 3"](https://gist.github.com/mhucka/567e1030c3b1de8c3b98c7d82778a957) in the section on [Loading MathJax](https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/arithmatex/#loading-mathjax), writing the following in a Markdown input file,

```
\\[
\Sigma_n
\\]
```

produces

[image]

Changing the MkDocs config file to add `tex_block_wrap` like this,

```
markdown_extensions:
  - footnotes
  - pymdownx.arithmatex:
      tex_block_wrap: ['\\\\[', '\\\\]']
  - pymdownx.highlight
  - pymdownx.superfences
```

does not change the output. I've tried variations on the number of `\` characters to no effect.  I've tried similar configuration changes on the MathJax side by adding the following to my `mathjax-config.js` file:

```
window.MathJax = {
    tex: {
        displayMath: [ ["\\\\[", "\\\\]"] ],
    },
....
```

and variations on the number of `\` characters there too, but without success.

**How can I get Arithmatex+MathJax in MkDocs to allow the use of `\\[` and `\\]` as display math delimeters?**

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use `\(` or `\[` in your Markdown file. Arithmatex converts `$` to inline math and `$$` to block math. See the examples in Arithmatex's documents. Following the instruction there, I got it to work in both generic and non-generic modes.

The .js file for generic mode is

```
window.MathJax = {
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [ ["\\(","\\)"] ],
    displayMath: [ ["\\[","\\]"] ],
    processEscapes: true,
    processEnvironments: true
  },
  options: {
    ignoreHtmlClass: ".*",
    processHtmlClass: "arithmatex"
  }
};
```

In markdown files, you can use either `\(` or `$` for inline math. Arithmatex converts `$` pairs to `\(` and `\)`. If you use `\[`, do not escape the backslash, i.e., NOT `\\(`.